# Mybb Update Query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, mybb

I've got a function in my mybb-forum. It's part of a plugin that tracks relies to certain forums and displays the date in on the memberpage (among other things).

This part is for when a user deleted his post. It's supposed to then find the last post before the deleted one in the set forums and to display that (older) date on the memberpage of that user.

However the update-query does not work and I don't know what the problem is.

Here is my code. There is no error but it does not write into the database either.

```
function lastippost_update($pid)
{ 
    global $db, $mybb;
    $query = $db->simple_select("posts","fid,uid,dateline","pid='{$pid}'");
    $post = $db->fetch_array($query);
    if ($mybb->settings['lastippost'] != '')
    {
            $ipids = $mybb->settings['lastippost'];
            if (in_array($post['fid'], $ipids))
            {
                    $ipquery = $db->write_query("SELECT uid,dateline FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts WHERE fid IN ($ipids) AND uid='".$post['uid']."' ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1");
                    $ippost = $db->fetch_array($ipquery);
                    $db->update_query("users", array('lastippost' => $ippost['dateline']), "uid='".$ippost['uid']."'");
            }
    }
```

}

$ipids is a comma-separated list of forum ids.

---

I dunno if that helps but I have another bit of rather similar code **that does work**:

```
             $ipids = $mybb->settings['lastippost'];
             $ipquery = $db->write_query("SELECT uid, dateline FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts WHERE fid IN ($ipids) ORDER BY uid,dateline DESC");
             while ($ippost = mysql_fetch_assoc($ipquery))
             {
                     if($ippost['uid'] != $lastuid)
                     {
                             $db->update_query("users", array('lastippost' => $ippost['dateline']), "uid='".$ippost['uid']."'");
                     }
                     $lastuid = $ippost['uid'];
             }
```

Comment: Have you added any debug to make sure that `$post` is returning what you are expecting?

Comment: Didn't you just delete the post that you are trying to select `uid='".$post['uid']`?

Comment: @Paul Mybb works with hooks. The hook I'm using here is set before deleting so it should run after selecting the post but before actually deleting it.

Comment: @Theo: Yes $post contains what it's supposed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found my problem:

```
$ipids = $mybb->settings['lastippost'];
```

The above is a string. I need it to be for the select query. But this part hier obviously refers to an array:

```
if (in_array($post['fid'], $ipids))
```

It may not be the best solution but now I've done something like this and it works:

```
$ipids = $mybb->settings['lastippost'];
$ipids2 = explode(",", trim($ipids));
```

The first is used for the select query and the second one for the in_array

Thanks for the help! (I'm still open to suggestions for more elegant solutions :) )